# Optimization-Coordinate closest to origin

Tags: calculus, optimization

The problem is:
Find the coordinate(s) of the points on $y^2=2.5(x+1)$ nearest to the origin.
I keep getting $x=-1.25$ using the distance formula and derivative. This is obviously wrong because the domain of $x$ is $x \geq -1$.
Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: I'm pretty new to representing math online but for anyone who wants to see what I did I'll display it very crudely.  $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(\sqrt{2.5x+2.5}-0)^2}$ since $y=\sqrt{2.5x+2.5}$ and then, after simplifying, I take the derivative and get: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+1.25}{\sqrt{x^2+2.5x+2.5}}.$$ Setting $dy/dx=0$ yields $x=-1.25$. Sorry for the sloppiness of my work.

Comment: How did you get $-1.25$? Please show us how you got to the result

Comment: Your derivative calculation is correct. However, the curve is only defined for $x\ge -1$. The square of the distance $x^2+2.5(x+1)$ is steadily increasing from $x=-1$  on. (We can see this using the derivative, or without). So the minimum distance is reached at $x=-1$.  An interesting instance of an endpoint minimum.